# Grails Mail port configuration

Tags: grails, email

I am trying to send mail through grails mail plugin. I configured according to the documentation, and also followed few blog posts (http://blog.lourish.com/2010/04/02/sending-asynchronous-html-email-in-grails-with-activemq-jms-and-gmail/). That post mention that the closure way of declaring the configuration overrides others, but not true. Anyway I tried both approach, but seems like the port is still use the smtp default one. I get the below exception.

```
exception: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Now, I wrote a small program directly using the java mail library, and I could send the mail with that. The configuration is shown below. tried additional config "mail.smtp.port":"465"", but no change.. used the parameters mentioned in the above blog post, result same

```
    grails {
   mail {
     host = "smtp.gmail.com"
     port = "465"  
     username = "mylogin@gmail.com"
     password = "mypwd"
     props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
            // "mail.smtp.port":"465",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
   }
}
```

thanks in advance..

Update: It is not port or firewall config, as when I made a grails application from scratch, and tried with the same config, everything works. Also, asked in grails forum http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-mail-mailSender-does-not-have-config-values-td2237704.html#a2237704 . Hope get a lead to try.

Comment: I worked on a project the other day with a similar issue. In the end we found that it was a firewall issue and that the application was actually trying to send on the alternative port. For us the exception was giving a misleading message about port 25. I cant remember the exact details because it was late at night and I just wanted to get home! :-) Good luck

Comment: wow!! that makes it difficult.. but, I turned off the firewall, and as I said, the plain java mail program with the same above configuration works fine :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the issue.. I had previously installed Nimble plugin, which also has a mail configuration injected into my application(NimbleConfig.groovy). It worked after I set the mail parameters as in my conf.groovy. I did not see that mailSender is initialized with the nimble config values, and only initialized once from my conf.groovy.. So, I am not sure about the reason, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the help of this setting

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 587
        username = "xyz@gmail.com"
        password = "mypassword"
        props = ["mail.debug": "true",
                "mail.smtp.protocol": "smtps",
                "mail.smtp.auth": "true",
                "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "true",
                "mail.smtp.host": "smtp.gmail.com",
                "mail.smtp.user": "xyz@gmail.com",
                "mail.smtp.password": "mypassword"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to assign port property an integer value:
port = 465
It works fine for me!
Good luck!